# Cases where use of tuple is a must

Tags: python, list, tuples

In Python, the only difference between a list and a tuple that I know of is **"lists are mutable but tuples are not"**. But as far as I believe, it depends on whether the coder wants to risk mutability or not.

So I was wondering whether there are any cases where the use of a tuple over a list is a must. Things that can not be done with a list but can be done with a tuple?

Comment: Tuples are used for packing/unpacking return values. As far as I'm aware, this cannot be done with lists.

Comment: @ltn100: you should try it.  Unpacking work with any sequence, including lists.

Comment: @Ned: thanks, I've never used it with other sequence types. I had naively assumed that it was a special property of tuples.

Comment: This isn't really an answer (since this question seems to be asking about functionality), but when your structure has a natural limit (such as `(x, y)` coordinates when limited to a 2D plane), a tuple should be used.  `[x, y]` is just weird.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use tuples as keys in dictionaries and insert tuples into sets:

```
>>> {}[tuple()] = 1
>>> {}[list()] = 1 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Which is basically a result of a `tuple` being hashable while a `list` isn't:

```
>>> hash(list())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> hash(tuple())
3527539
```

Comment: Just make sure not to modify fields used in the hash computation after a tuple containing it has been inserted in the set/dict.  This is the same rule as when putting mutable types in sets/dicts, but the extra layer of indirection (and confusion induced by tuples being "immutable") makes it somewhat less obvious to spot.

Comment: @Andre: The standard Python types are either mutable or hashable. If you follow that convention with your own types, you won't run into this problem.

Comment: @NiklasB.: except that the default Python style makes mutable classes (meaning 99.9% of classes people write are mutable) and having types that are both mutable and hashable is immensely useful (albeit a little tricky).

Comment: @André how can a type be mutable and hashable at once? From the answer I suppose mutable types are not hashable?

Comment: @tarashish you can define a `__hash__()` function for any class

Comment: @tarashish: the built-in Python types are either mutable or hashable by convention.  However, you can add a `__hash__()` method for any type.  The trick is that if the `__hash__()` method depends on mutable fields, the object's hash code can change over time.  This should be avoided at all costs because it means you can create a situation where an object is in a `dict`, but lookup for the key fails because the object's fields have changed.  Since it's confusing and error prone, it's considered good practice to avoid adding a `__hash__()` function to a mutable type.

Answer (score 13):

The answer by @Otto is very good.  The only thing I have to add to it is that when you open things up to 3rd party extensions, you really need to consult the documentation.  Some functions/methods may expect one or the other data-type (or have different results depending on which one you use).  One example is using tuples/lists to index a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(50)
a[[1,4,8]] #array([1, 4, 8])
a[(1,4,8)] #IndexError
```

**EDIT**

Also, a quick timing test shows that tuple creation is MUCH FASTER than list creation:

```
import timeit
t=timeit.timeit('[1,2,3]',number=10000000)
print (t)
t=timeit.timeit('(1,2,3)',number=10000000)
print (t)
```

which is good to keep in mind.  In other words, do:

```
for num in (8, 15, 200):
    pass
```

instead of:

```
for num in [8, 15, 200]:
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

Also, the now obsolete string formatting using the `%` operator requires the argument list to be a tuple. A list would be treated as single argument:

```
>>> "%s + %s" % [1, 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
>>> "%s + %s" % (1, 2)
'1 + 2'
```

Comment: `"%s" % [1,2]` - it *requires* tuples only if you have to specify *multiple* arguments.